# How to explicitly get a value after posting a form?

Tags: php, post, request

```
<form> 
  <div class="[ form-group ] correct_answer">
      <input type="checkbox" name="correct_answer_or_not ' . $question_id .'"  id="' . $question_id . '" autocomplete="off" />
             <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                  <label for="' . $question_id . '" class="[ btn btn-primary ]">
                      <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                      <span> </span>
                  </label>
                  <label for="' . $question_id . '" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                       Correct Answer
                  </label>
             </div>
  </div>
<button  type="submit" name="submit_review">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hi guys,

What I have here is a checkbox that is been placed inside a form, and basically every time you make a post, I get to know which of the question id related checkbox is ticked.

so if I check one of the boxes and do this,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_review'])) {

    die(var_dump($_POST));

}
```

I get the output to be like :

```
{ ["correct_answer_or_not_44"]=> string(2) "on"}
```

As I expected I "correct_answer_or_not_" stayed the same and the digit 44 is based on the question id for that particular checkbox.

But my question is is there anyway I can explicitly as which checkbox has been post ? instead of me doing $_POST

I want to implement it so that I know question id 44 has made the post.

I believe I have explained the problem in detail, if there is anything you guys like to know please ask.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't included the code to show where this $question_id is changing, it is in a for loop and thought I didn't need to share that, since my question is not related to it

Comment: `type="checkbox" name="correct_answer_or_not[]" value="'.$question_id.'"`?

Comment: based on @Eihwaz comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="correct_answer_or_not[' . $question_id .']" />` you can get associative arrays from html forms as well

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get an answer for this question, I basically just did what both of these people said and it did what I expected it to do. Thanks again guys

```
<input type="checkbox" name="correct_answer_or_not[]" value="'.$question_id.'"  id="' . $question_id . '" autocomplete="off" />
```